AWS Pinpoint Push Notifications Not Delivered Despite Successful Send Status
I'm experiencing an issue with AWS Pinpoint not sending push notifications, despite it returning a successful send status
Here are the steps I've taken and the problem I'm facing:

I uploaded the Firebase service account JSON file as token credentials into the AWS Pinpoint Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) console.

When I test sending a sample FCM notification to an active device token using the Test Messaging Tab in AWS Pinpoint, it indicates that the notification was successfully sent.

However, the device does not receive any notification.

Additionally, the Firebase Cloud Messaging console does not show any successful send reports.

AWS amplify configuration on react-native application
{
  PushNotification: {
      Pinpoint: {
        appId: 'be923ab029724fdf9af91a869282db7c',
        region: 'us-east-1',
      },
    },
  }



Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest troubleshooting steps to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
